# WCF over named pipes

Tags: wcf, windows-services, named-pipes

Hi I have a problem with following scenario:

There is a windows service running which spawns several processes. These processes open a WCF service host over a named pipe binding. Now the parent windows service tries to ping (connect) to the child processes using the wcf proxy over the well known named pipe. This, however fails saying: "Endpoint not found"

If I run the parent process as a console application it works fine.

Any ideas? I was thinking about permissions but the child processes should inherit the permission of the service, besides they are in the same session as well.

thanks,
Christoph

Comment: are all those child processes using the same named pipe?

Comment: I ask since you say "...over the well known named pipe" - almost sounds like you're trying to use a single named pipe for several child processes

Comment: can you show us how such a child process is created, and how it created its WCF endpoint(s)? How does the parent attempt to call the child processes?

Comment: No, each child process opens its own named pipe. Anyway the same code works fine if I run the parent process in the console and not as a service. So the problem must have to do with the fact that I run the parent process as a windows service under "Local System Account"

Answer (score 0):

"Endpoint not found" could be that it cannot find the endpoint. Or it could be that it cannot find the configuration for the endpoint.

My best guess is that you are missing the client side configuration for the endpoint.

Comment: In the case of NetNamedPipeBinding, "Endpoint not found" does not necessarily mean that the endpoint does not exist. The exact same error is seen if the endpoint exists but the client process attempting to communicate with it does not have the necessary security rights to see the shared memory object used by the WCF service-side stack to publish the pipe name currently in use. See details at http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/05/19/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-1.aspx etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but the problem is that the service runs with elevated privileges, and therefore the client needs to be elevated too.